# Calling a Ruby method via a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, button, methods

Quick question, what's the best way to call a ruby method via a button? At the moment, the button will only call a JS function but I need it carry out a Ruby method.

Basically, the button has to compare an Excel spreadsheet with my database and display the difference in a table on another page. How can I create that page without generating a new model? Sorry for the stupid question, but I've only been sticking to the conventions, hence I am unsure as to how I should create a new page.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: what do you mean by ruby method? you want to call a controller action from a form button?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. I want to call a ruby method (compareExcel), which fills in data into the DB and displays the results in an HTML table, all via the press of one button

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) method.

```
<%= button_to "Compare Excel", :action => "compareExcel" %>
```

Comment: Ok, had a look at that method and it seems to do the trick. But how do I get it to redirect to another page which would then display the output of my method?

Comment: `render :action => 'display_excel'` will show your view template `display_excel.html.erb` with the data in context. So if you store your data in an instance variable (like `@result_excel`), you may use that data then in the view.

Comment: apologies for my ignorance, but where to i place the `render....` code? in the button_to method?

Comment: I believe render should go in the controller action. [controller guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)